# Asking superior to mark a document with 印鑑{いんかん}

Tags: word-choice, nuances, business-japanese

What is the proper way to ask a superior to sign their hanko for approval? When I need a superior to sign their hanko for a routine log (not for reviewing a document or stuff, just routine logging off stuff out of the office), I am hesitant in saying "please sign."

I think I usually say:
判子{はんこ}を押してください。

But I think the polite form in the office is:
判子{はんこ}を押していただけませんか？

But this sounds too formal, and I do not hear in verbal form the phrase 「～いただけませんか」.  Though, I do hear this in the service sector like when talking to a customer.

I try to notice how the other Japanese do it, and they just give the sheet to the manager and usually just say unrelated things. Any idea, or is the verb wrong, or do you use other words than 判子 like 印字してください？

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to your question, but why not just try out 判子を押していただけませんか on your boss? It might turn out to be the wrong level of politeness, but it's not so wrong that he will burst into flames and die. Best possible outcome: you get a laugh and create an in-joke. You can always experiment higher in politeness and come down. (Experimenting with more rude and coming up would not be advisable). For more: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2420/you-dont-have-to-be-so-polite-really/2429#2429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say

`すみません、判子をいただけますか？`

It's just barely formal/respectful, but that's all that's needed for a phrase which is just a formality.

Like "Could you sign this, please?"

Comment: Yes, and I think you can also say like 'すみません、こちらに判子頂けますか？'/'すみません、（こちらに）判子お願いできますか？'/'すみません、こちらに判子お願いします'/'すみません、（こちらに）判子頂いてもよろしいですか？'.　Usually I don't put the particle を after 判子 when I talk.