# How is this verb being conjugated and contracted?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> " こんな馬鹿みたいな帽子かぶせやがって！！”
>
> " こんなくそみたいな帽子かぶせやがって！！”
>
> " こんなくそみたいな帽子かぶせんじゃねーよ！！”

I believe I'm looking at a conjugation and contraction of the verb かぶる. What is the original conjugation and what is taken out in the contraction?

Comment: I think it's「かぶせる」(a causative verb??), not「かぶる」...?

Comment: i had a caption I was trying to translate into japanese, which pictured a dolphin wearing a shitty hat, and saying  "I hate wearing this shitty hat". I tried the passive causative of かぶる (so it would mean more like "I had to wear this shitty hat") but was given these instead. so i guess I could translate these better as "I had to put on this shitty hat". but if the person wearing the shitty hat is saying this line, why would かぶせる be used? Isn't it used more for putting things on something other than the speaker? (ie the speaker uses かぶせる when they they put a hat on someone else)?

Comment: Your first and the second sentences do not differ where it it relevant for the question.

Comment: Maybe students of japanese will benefit from how some people translate "shitty". it was an altruistic impulse that led me to list all three examples.

Comment: @Chocolate. I guess the question arose because かぶせる is ambiguous when by itself. (1) It is a verb on its own. (2) It can also be formed by the potential form of かぶす.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"かぶせやがって" is just the "-te form" of "かぶせやがる", which you accepted an answer to [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/how-to-use-the-inflection-%E3%82%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B) so I guess you know the basic meaning.

This use of the "-te" form is essentially an accusation. You often see it combined with "どうするつもりだ" or something like that: "(What do you mean by) + putting a stupid hat like this on me?!". But even when the utterance ends at the "-te" as in your example, the meaning is the same: the dolphin is not happy about having had the hat put on him.

Incidentally, "かぶせる", meaning "put a hat (on someone)", is related to the verb "かぶる", but it is not a "conjugation" of it in the sense that I think you mean. Reason: in modern Japanese you make verbs causative by adding the affix "-(a)seru" to the stem, and that would give you "kabur-(a)seru" in this case, not "kabu-seru". So although "kabuseru" is obviously related to "kaburu", and it even looks like the same "-seru" is used, it's better to consider "kabuseru" as a different word, and not just a "conjugated form" of "kaburu" -- at least in modern Japanese.

(Note that the derived form "kaburaseru" is actually used sometimes. I'm not sure if it has different patterns of use from "kabuseru" or whether it should just be considered a variation that arose precisely because "kabuseru" can't be derived from "kaburu" directly in modern Japanese.)

In your last example, ”かぶせん" is a contracted version of "かぶせるん" (which arguably is itself a contracted version of "かぶせるの"). る and るん turning into ん is pretty common in casual speech. "何言ってるの" -> "何言ってんの", "だから言ってるんじゃん" -> "だから言ってんじゃん".

"-n janee" is a standard form way of creating an insulting negative imperative. Here the dolphin is saying something which we might translate into English as "Don't put stupid hats like this on me[, poop-face]!" -- well, ideally something more idiomatic, but I think you get the idea. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/what-is-the-difference-between-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%EF%BC%81-and-%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AD%E3%81%87%E3%81%9E) for some more on that part.

Comment: thanks. I was puzzled about the "かぶせるん" <"かぶせるの" contraction. I see that this can be a question form with the の, ( maybe not here though) so is こんなくそみたいな帽子かぶせんじゃねーよ！！” also a question, like "Why do I have to put on this shitty hat?" ? I was also interested in the kaburu / kabuseru relation, thanks for touching on that. do you think it merits another question? I am interested in how they are related, how they diverged...

Comment: @yadokari No problem. The じゃねーよ ending means that this isn't a question, but if it was just "こんなくそみたいな帽子かぶせるの?" it could mean "[Seriously?] You're going to put a stupid hat like this on me?", I guess. Re kabuseru/kaburu, sure, why not another question?　Worst that can happens is noone answers :)

Comment: @Matt さん・・「くそみたいな」は乱暴な表現ですので、「かぶせるの」では優しすぎて、相容れません。「くそみたいな」を使うならば「かぶせんのかよ?!」などでなくてはおかしいと思います。

Comment: @Chocolate That's a good point. My comment addresses the syntax alone but pragmatic issues should also be taken into consideration.